# FIleNotFoundError Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
if boolErrorsOnly :
    mfile = "NewPayrollExports\Admin_ErrorsOnly_" + m0weekbeg + "_" + m0weekend + ".csv"
else:
    mfile = "NewPayrollExports\\Admin_" + m0weekbeg + "_" + m0weekend+".csv"

#Copy the field list to csv file
with open(mfile,'r+', newline='') as mhvupload_csv:
    writer = csv.writer(mhvupload_csv)
    writer.writerow(strFieldList)
```

I'm trying to write to a csv file but I get this error in the with line. I have this:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'NewPayrollExports\\Admin_ErrorsOnly_20200501_20200515.csv'
```

Comment: make sure your path is correct

Comment: My guess would be, the file does not exist...

Comment: I think it's the folder that doesn't exist. You are writing into the file, so it's ok the file is new, but if you don't have the folder, you can't create new files.

Comment: if you open it in append mode, you can still write to it and it creates it if it doesn't exist - "a"

Comment: I have the folder and I have a directory already set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you use 'r' mode for file that does not exist.
Use 'w' mode to write to file.

Example:

```
with open(mfile,'w+', newline='') as mhvupload_csv:
    writer = csv.writer(mhvupload_csv)
    writer.writerow(strFieldList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full path, IE

./NewPayrollExports/Admin_ErrorsOnly.....

also, your slashes are the wrong way

Answer (score 0):

Use "./NewPayrollExports/Admin_ErrorsOnly_" + m0weekbeg + "_" + m0weekend + ".csv"

if the file is in the same directory as of this program and use ../ if you want to go up from the current directory of the program.

Cheers,
Amol